# How to show Recently Searched Products without using Widget on HomePage (Luma). Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, widget, luma-theme, home-page

I want to show **recently searched products** on **homepage** without using **Recently Viewed Products Widget** I want to get this in my custom block and also want to show this in my custom **.phtml** file how it would be possible?

Comment: You can use recently viewed product options instead of recently search, because when you search you will get list of other products as well.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake... actually it is *Recently Viewed Products Widget* now I want to create the block to get all recently viewed product... how it would be possible Sir?

Comment: Please check my ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please create a static block with the following code

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" uiComponent="widget_recently_viewed" page_size="5" show_attributes="name,image,price,learn_more" show_buttons="add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist" template="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" type_name="Recently Viewed Products"}}
```

Now, Call that static block in your phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('recently_viewed')->toHtml(); ?>
```

You can manage it via XML using following way.

```
<!-- Configured recently viewed products block -->
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" name="recently_viewed" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
        <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
        <!-- 'Product attributes to show' configuration -->
        <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price,learn_more</argument>
        <!-- 'Buttons to show' configuration -->
        <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Please clear cache and view some product pages, so the viewed product will where you want.

Comment: Sir it gives me an error
`Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Reports' block's name: 'product\widget\viewed_0'`

Comment: Sorry Its my mistake, I have added wrong block before, I have just updated my ans, so please check and let me know if any issue

Comment: Sir now it gives me `Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined index: attributes in /var/www/html/magento231/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 176`

Comment: Sir n I'm showing this on **Homepage** mean in `grid.phtml` may coz of this file it give me these issues

Comment: Sir I also tried `<?php //echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>` this does't give me any error but it also does't show any recent searched products

Comment: Sir did u check it?

Comment: @AsadKhan I have tried and its working fine for me, please check my updated ans and let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: Thank u so much Sir it works for me but I want to do this without using Block is it possible???

Comment: Its was possible on older version of magento, but in latest version we are not able to add uiComponent attribute for recently viewed block if we use it directly in phtml, so we have to do it by using block or using xml.
Hope you understand :)

Comment: Please accept my ans so it will useful to others, Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update the answer by giving me the `.xml` method as well

Comment: I have added .xml method as well, so please check and let me know if any issue.

Comment: So my team Lead is saying that it is a Magento **bug** to not get data without *Static Block* or *Widget* n now my task is to fix that bug n I even dont have idea from where I need to start